# how can I repair unrecognizable sd card

Tags: sd-card, mount, kali, fsck

This SD card has Kali loaded for Raspberry pi 3.

Some how I corrupted sd card by editing config.txt file in windows 10 machine, after then sd card was unrecognizable by neither machines windows or the raspberry pi with Debian, but if I put this sd card in raspi it will boot to the kali desktop.

Corruption I had in this sd card causing somethings don’t work in desktop like, wifi connection, it said it’s connected, but if ping any where it comes back with unreachable site, if I ran ifconfig there are ip, mask, and gateway all there, but when I try ifdown or ifup it comes with unknown interface wlan0.

So clearly something still corrupted I want to reflash sd card, but other machines don’t recognizing this sd card.

I tried fsck to itself but it said drive is mounted so can’t do anything.

Comment: Can you not reformat the SD card? Can the other computers even recognise that the SD card is plugged in?

Comment: Windows machine doesn't even know it plugged in. Raspi doesn't know either so I thought it was goner but  when plug in to boot raspi it will boot to X windows so it's still live. I couldn't  format nor  reflash to reset OS. No machines recognize to format the SD card.

Comment: I got it fixed some how, this is weird problem. I download SD card Formatter,  plugged in SD card to USB SD card reader to gain a drive letter so I can tried to format SD card,  first time it tried to format with out error showing busy for 10 minutes so I stop it and tried it for second times it worked,  then I was able to reflash Kali again and it seems work better than before,  I was able to edit config.txt got right resolution on display  had no problem with SD card any more.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I ended up inserting the cards into a digital camera, formatting them and plugging the camera into a computer. I left the card in the camera, ran DiskUtility (OSX - what ever OS your using use the default formatting tool)

Then I ran the SD formatter tool, followed by Etcher.

It might be over kill, you can probably skip reformatting with the OS tool